# IPython print output is broken

Tags: python, configuration, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I installed Jupyter and Ipython in a virtual environment. Whenever I type something in the IPython REPL and press enter, the output is prepended with a bunch of repeated garbage:

```py
In [2]: print("Hello, world!")
```

```py
line='print("Hello, world!")\n', last_line=b'', encoding=None
print
(
"Hello, world!"
)


line=b'', last_line='print("Hello, world!")\n', encoding=None

line='print("Hello, world!")\n', last_line=b'', encoding=None
print
(
"Hello, world!"
)


line=b'', last_line='print("Hello, world!")\n', encoding=None

line='print("Hello, world!")\n', last_line=b'', encoding=None
print
(
"Hello, world!"
)


line=b'', last_line='print("Hello, world!")\n', encoding=None
Hello, world!
```

```
In [3]: 2 + 2
```

```
line='2 + 2\n', last_line=b'', encoding=None
2
+
2


line=b'', last_line='2 + 2\n', encoding=None

line='2 + 2\n', last_line=b'', encoding=None
2
+
2


line=b'', last_line='2 + 2\n', encoding=None

line='2 + 2\n', last_line=b'', encoding=None
2
+
2


line=b'', last_line='2 + 2\n', encoding=None

line='2 + 2', last_line=b'', encoding=None
2
+
2
line='', last_line='2 + 2', encoding=None
Out[3]: 4
```

This garbage output occurs in both IPython REPL in a terminal, and Jupyter notebooks in a browser.

I'm running Windows 10 with Python 3.8.1. The package versions are:

- jupyter 1.0.0
- ipython 7.17.0
- notebook 6.1.1

These were installed via Poetry. I installed the exact same Python and package versions on a separate PC (running Linux) and the problem did not appear, so I suspect something is configured wrong on my Windows PC rather than the problem being a bug in IPython.

How do I make it print like normal again?

Comment: Please list your complete set of packages and your environment variables

Comment: Does the normal python repl work?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. Try to use the following code in your script to see if output of encoding changes. This indicates where the problem may reside.

```py
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

... your code ...

print "something"
```

2. If you print using pprint: You may want to try the `%pprint` command to turn pretty print on or off.
3. If logging (import logging) is active:

`logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)`

See also: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'reload' is not defined`. I imported it from `importlib` then got `AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'`. I'm on Python 3, not 2.

Comment: Toggling `%pprint` did nothing. I tried the logging part but it resulted in an unhandled exception in event loop: `Exception [WinError 995] The I/O operation has been aborded because of either a thread exit or an application request, press ENTER to continue` (full traceback too long to fit in a comment)

Comment: I downgraded my Python version to 3.7, the problem did not appear there. I've reported it as a bug on IPython's github.

Comment: I don't think its related to python itself. Downgrade resets somethings for sure. It looks like something is compiled in debugging mode. What happens if you upgrade again to py3.8.1? If it appears again then downgrade each of the three: jupyter 1.0.0, ipython 7.17.0 or notebook 6.1.1 until solved. Reason: I'm running Win10 and 3.8.1. as well and no such output as you posted shown.

Comment: Upgrading back to 3.8 makes it break again. I have two entirely separate Python virtual environments with identical packages, with the only difference being the Python version. The 3.7 one works fine, the 3.8 one has the bad output. Also it turns out that `jupyter` and `notebook` are irrelevant here; it happens with just installing the `ipython` package (along with its dependencies) and launching its REPL.